# scanf with %8x auto adds 00 at the beginning if user input with 0x?

Tags: c

am kinda stuck on how to make it work, I need to get 8 Hex digits from user.and I am trying to get only the first 8 digits if the user enter more than 8 by using

```
scanf("%8x", iPtr); //iPtr is an int pointer that's why i don't use &.
```

It works if the user does not type: `0x` at the beginning, but if they enter: `0xffffffffffff`
the result of iPtr is: `0x00FFFFFF`
It auto add 2 `0`s in front of the `F`s...

if i only use `%x`, it will work fine but getting the last 8 digits instead. and i want the first 8 digits...

Comment: `scanf` doesn't add anything. It simply gets the first eight characters, which are `0xffffff`. It's `printf` that adds the zeros.

Comment: BTW `iPtr` should be an `unsigned int *`, not an `int *`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `8` in the format string means to read at most 8 characters from the input. So if the input is `0xffffffffff` then the input sequence is `0xffffff` which matches the output you got.  (I assume you used `%08x` in the printf format string, otherwise you would have not seen the extra zeroes in the output).

Unfortunately there is no combination of `scanf` options that means "read 10 characters if it started with `0x` or `0X` and read 8 characters otherwise".  You would have to implement that logic yourself, using other input functions.

Comment: thanks again, I hit the accept answer :) first time user... live and learn!